# Sidebar random author spotlight

Tags: sidebar, author

I'm trying to utilize the authors from wordpress to create a spotlight block in the sidebar that selects 1 random author from multiple users and only displays that 1 users information. I want to include the author's display name, a thumbnail, snippet of their bio and a link to the full author page. I haven't found any plugins that support this. I'm not a PHP/MySQL wiz so custom writing a function is a bit outside my abilities however I can read it and follow the code.  What I have so far is:

```
<?php 
    global $wpdb;
    $ids = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id from {$wpdb->usermeta} where ({$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key='wp_capabilities') and ({$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value >0 )" );
    $user_id = rand(1,count($ids));
    $wpdb->show_errors(); 
?>
<h2><?php get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $user_id ); ?></h2>
<img class="left" src="" alt="<?php print $selected_user; ?>" />
<p><?php get_the_author_meta( 'user_description', $user_id ); ?> <a href="<?php get_the_author_meta( 'user_url', $user_id ); ?>">read more</a>
```

This returns an array but I am unsure of what to do to get the output I need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I opted instead to use a category and use posts instead due to the time crunch the project is under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cut a lot of steps out of this if you use `get_users()` instead of your custom SQL query. You can then select a random user out of that array using `array_rand()` (native PHP function, not a wordpress function) and it will return the key you should be using.  Here's an example:

```
$users = get_users( $your_params );
$id = array_rand( $users, 1 );

$user = $users[$id];
```

This will leave you with `$user`, which will contain a user object with just about everything you could want on a user...or at least the ability to obtain what you need. `get_avatar()` will do the thumbnail...assuming you want the default.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your query results in an error on a current WP install. i get the error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" when I echo $user.

Comment: That's because user is an object, not a string...I made this pretty clear in my answer. You cannot echo objects. Try `print_r( $user );` if you want to see what the object contains.