# Randomize Users

Tags: user-meta, users, wp-user-query

I'm trying to randomly display my users and I was wondering if I could edit the answer on this page to suit my needs (multiple users instead of a single user): [Sidebar random author spotlight](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42378/sidebar-random-author-spotlight)

Here's my code (I can easily switch to `WP_user_query` if need be)

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
        'exclude' => array(1),
    );
    $users = get_users( $args );
foreach( $users as $user ) { ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see an "orderby Rand()" parameter for either [`get_users`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) or [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). There is a filter called [`pre_user_query`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/user.php#L529) that could be used but I am not sure I see the benefit of that when `shuffle` will randomize the array you already have.

```
$args = array(
    'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
    'exclude' => array(1),
);
$users = get_users( $args );
shuffle($users);
var_dump($users);
```

Comment: I ended up using shuffle which worked perfectly!